# Using GNUplot to plot letter frequency Plot

Tags: gnuplot, visualization

I am planning to use GNUPlot for plotting frequency of letters which occur in a dictionary. Example:

```
அ   7496
ஆ   2395
இ   3285
ஈ   390
உ   3133
ஊ   530
எ   1189
ஏ   705
```

The language set which I am using is Tamil. It has more than 200 Letters to be plotted. Hence whichever way I am trying to plot it, there is clustering of data and I cannot see the plotted data properly.

I am reading the data from a file stored as csv which has letters in one column and frequency in another column.

Is there a way to plot frequency of letters  without overlap in a languague which has over 200 letters ?

Comment: Ok, so what is your actual question?

Comment: @Christoph   Is there a way to plot frequency of letters  without overlap in a languague which has over 200 letters

Comment: It's still not clear what the problem is.  you can in general use 
`set style histogram; 
plot  'data.csv' using 2:xticlabels(1)`
to do the plot and `set xtics rotate by 90 right font "Arial,6"` to rotate the labels by 90°, and use Arial of size 6pt. There's no automatic way, you have to adjust it by hand.

Comment: @sweber I think I got it . The tweak was that ,
1) I took log to the base 10 of the frequecy values
2)Then it got reduced to numbers between .0something to 6.something
3)I pasted the label in 3rd colum (copy paste ) 
அ 7496 அ 3.8748295779
ஆ 2395 ஆ 3.3793055178
இ 3285 இ 3.5165353739
ஈ 390 ஈ 2.591064607
உ 3133 உ 3.4959603949
ஊ 530 ஊ 2.7242758696


4)Set ytics to .5 
5)Set xtics to 30 
6)Ran this command 
plot 'filename.csv' using (column(0)):4:3 with labels